# Android Studio 3.2 Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

After migration to Android Studio 3.2 layouts with "CustomFontView" initialize with warning and no preview avalable

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.reset(Paint_Delegate.java:1256)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.<init>(Paint_Delegate.java:1210)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nInit(Paint_Delegate.java:701)
at android.graphics.Paint.nInit(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:478)
at android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.<init>(ColorDrawable.java:49)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:302)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:246)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:289)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:448)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:585)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Class `android.graphics.Typeface` is visible under library root folder

Usages:

`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'`

`compileSdkVersion 27`

`buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment success build is to using of following versions of SDK and buildTools

`buildToolsVersion "28.0.0-rc2"`

`compileSdkVersion 'android-P'`

and migration from `support` libraries to `androidx`

```
def x_version = '1.0.0-alpha1'
def x_constraint_version = '1.1.0'
dependencies {
   implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$x_version"
   implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$x_version"
   implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$x_constraint_version"
   implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$x_version"
   implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$x_version"
}
```